# Ember fingerprinting

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, fingerprinting

I am new to ember and am running into an issue deploying an ember app. I am using ember server to server my ember app that was built with fingerprinting enabled.

`/app/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember build --environment=production`

When I run this in production mode, it works great, until I scale to multiple deployments.

`/app/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember server --port 80 --live-reload=false --environment $EMBER_ENV`

When I have more then one ember server instance in a load balancer, the fingerprint generated on each is different, even though they were the same build, and this causes an intermittent 404.

`172.x.x.x - - [18/Jul/2017:18:44:59 +0000] "GET /assets/vendor-a4e09847ae5ed0421fd631873a322bdb.js HTTP/1.1" 404`

- Is this fingerprint generated at run time and not build time?
- Is there any way I can make it a build time action?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I believe its build time, and it will generate it new fingerprint for every build

Comment: Just to verify: you *should not* user `ember server` for production! So why would you ever have multiple ember server instances running? You should use `ember build` to build your app, and then use a webserver ligke nginx , iis or apache to deploy the files to your clients.

Comment: Good to know, but now I'm curious why not use ember server in prod? What are it's limitations? 

Thanks

Comment: It was coded with development in mind, which impacts speed and security. It runs the broccoli file watch and rebuilds the app even with live reload disabled, for example. If you install an addon, you have to restart the server. There might be more subtle things.
You really should be building your app and using a production server like suggested.

Comment: Ultimately the issue was ember server rebuilds the project every time you run it, so thats why broccoli was generating a new fingerprint for each member in the load balancing group. I was not able to find a way to turn this off, so I switched over to serving the static content from nginx. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

It is a definitely a build time. A result of `ember build` is a `dist` folder with generated `index.html`, which contains references to fingerprinted assets, and CSS, JavaScript, image, etc. assets.

Make sure your `index.html` file is not cached and you correctly propagate content of `dist` folder to each node.

To see if it works with cache disabled you can open Developer Tools in Chrome, go to Network tab and check "Disable cache" option.

While it's great that you would want to cache and load balance your fingerprinted assets you need to be very careful with `index.html` as it should be always up to date with new builds.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It must be something in my deployment process then. I am building using a Dockerfile and deploying the same container multiple times which is what is confusing me, they should be exactly the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you execute `ember build` ONCE, but copy contents MULTIPLE TIMES. :) Check also your server caching settings. For example if response contains caching tags for example to cache content for 5 years.